# Klarmobile SurfStick - XS Stick W14 Networkmanager

Tags: network-manager, internet, usb-modem, wvdial

I try to use a Surfstick from Klarmobil,

Since I followed [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/XS_Stick_W14/) instructions (I used 2-5 more but am not allowed to link them here since reputation under 10), I was finally able to get the SurfStick - XS Stick W14 working.

Which means the green LED on the stick now is on (not flashing). As you can see within NetworkManager Interface there is one Entry for the Stick. After I used `wvdial` (I added an image here but this also counts as link). The output of `wvdial` also provides the information that I am connected

[terminal output of `wvdial`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge2iP.png).

But at this point, there is no further help. If disconnect from my LAN and want to use the Internet Chrome and Firefox telling me i am not connected.

What do I have to do now?

Comment: If you first disconnect from Lan, and after that start wvdial, does it work then? There seems to be a connection completed (see information on IP address, DNS etc). Maybe name service or routing is lost when disconnecting LAN after having connected to ppp0.

Comment: i tryed to do this but ther was no effect

Answer (score 1):

How I got it working for me was:

Using this config for `wvdial.conf`:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Phone = *99#
Username = "klarmobil"
Password = "klarmobil"
Stupid Mode = on
Dial Command = ATDT
Modem Type = USB Modem
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2
Init1 = ATZ

[Dialer klarmobil]
Carrier Check = on
Init3 = ATS0=0
Init4 = AT+COPS?
Init5 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.mobilcom"
ISDN = off
Dial Attempts = 3

[Dialer nopin]
Init2= AT+CPIN=""
Init3= AT+CLCK="SC",0,""
[Dialer umts]
Stupid Mode = on
Carrier Check = on
# Abfrage der hinterlegten APNs. Der erste Eintrag wird zur Einwahl verwendet.
Init2= AT+CGDCONT?
# Beispiele zum Setzen eigener APNs, zur Aktivierung Strichpunkt entfernen!
;Init3= AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","APN"
;Init3= AT+CGDCONT=2,"IP","surfo2"
;Init3= AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.mobilcom"
ISDN = off
```

And this Commands

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf -v 0x1c9e -p 0xf000
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9603
sudo wvdial umts
```

Then went to SystemConfig -> NetworkConfig -> Mobil Broadband -> **New Connection**

```
Provider -> other: "klarmobil"
APN : "internet.mobilcom"
```

(Just an example, settings vary depending on the ISP)

After this steps the Connection was fully established. Which means the LAN/WLAN Icon changed to something link **an "Mobile" like icon** in the top right corner.